# how do i open up android.support.v4.app.Fragment from an activity

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-fragments, android-activity

I asked this question before but most of u guys' answers are for the other fragment.
Basically how do i open a `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` from an `Activity`?

Comment: Make a container id in activity layout. And open fragment by simple instantiating fragment and replacing its instance in Fragment transaction . The process for both type of fragments is same just the import is diffrent

Comment: sample code pls? @Hulk

Answer (score 6):

Here is how..

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new SupportFragment())
                .commit();
```

Answer (score 1):

You could not open `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` from `android.app.Activity`.
You should use `android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity` instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
// Replace the container with the new fragment
ft.replace(R.id.your_placeholder, new FooFragment());
// or ft.add(R.id.your_placeholder, new FooFragment());
// Execute the changes specified
ft.commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is your activity layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/your_placeholder"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Then create a fragment by extending Fragment class.

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import com.example.goodfeetapp.MainActivity;
import com.example.goodfeetapp.R;
import com.example.goodfeetapp.adapter.BringAdapter;

public class Bring extends Fragment {
    public static String TAG = "Bring";

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gridview, container, false);


        return view;
    }
```

}

Now to replace this fragment in activity class using the following :

```
                        FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager()
                                .beginTransaction();
                        Bring bring = new Bring();

                        ft.replace(R.id.your_placeholder, bring,
                                Bring.TAG);
                        ft.addToBackStack(null);

                        ft.commit();
```

Comment: I dont understand the activity layout part. Do you mean the gridview.xml? where do i insert the id your_placeholder?

Comment: android:id="@+id/your_placeholder" is the container id. All fragments will be put in that container. Whenever you will replace a fragment you have to use this id. Consider that this id is a space i booked in activity and i am using that space to replace my fragments. And i can replace as many fragments i like.

Comment: it says = return() cannot be applied to:

Comment: gridview.xml is layout of a fragment. Whenever you create a fragment you should create a layout of it .  It is same as activity layout.

Comment: Do one thing extend your activity from FragmentActivity rather than Activity and when you will use it, use FragmentTransaction ft = getsupportFragmentManager() .beginTransaction(); and then i guess it will work fine

Comment: it still says incompatible types

Comment: Are your imports ok? import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;

Comment: dude you have to post your code. Cnt help you like that, if i can post it as an answer why c'nt you?

Comment: Use getSupportFragmentManager(); and not getFragmentManager();